# How to cancel Volley server request, during activity tranistions

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am having a drawer activity in which I am starting a fragment having a JSON request call, but before this request returns the response I am switching to another fragment through drawer item menu and the problem is when the main fragment data gets loaded then it's showing in the CHANGED fragment.
How to cancel volley request from another fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onStop () {
super.onStop();
if (mRequestQueue != null) {
mRequestQueue.cancelAll(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tag to your request. It will be identify every request. After that, your request queue has a cancelAll method, it is require a tag.

//Before you add your request to the queue, set the tag, the tag can be a string.

```
    yourRequest.setTag(tag);
```

After that, when you want to cancel your request :

```
   requestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
```

This will work only when your request is in queue.
If your request is already started then it will not work.
there is no way to undo/cancel an http request that's already begun.
You can use some logical part in your app to handle this situation.

After executing request ,In response of request you can check that is the loaded fragment is exactly the same as you want if yes then only load the data, otherwise not.